# Question about idempotent and Dominance Laws in Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

If I have the following statements:

For Idempotent:

Since **X * X = X**, would that imply that **~X * ~X = ~X**

For Dominance:

Since **X + 1 = 1** would that imply that **~X + 1 = 1**

Comment: You can easily check your statements using for example the method of [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Comment: Would this work also when simplifying any expression using Boolean theorems, in that case is truth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of substitution states that if $\varphi$ is a valid (fully parenthesized) formula in variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are arbitrary expressions, then if we substitute $e_i$ for $x_i$ in $\varphi$ (you have to substitute *all* occurrences of $x_i$ by $e_i$) we still get a valid formula. You can apply this principle to your examples.

Perhaps the principle will become easier to understand if we take an example from algebra. Consider the identity $(x+y)(x-y) = x^2-y^2$. If we substitute $2a$ for $x$ and $1+a$ for $y$ then we get $((2a)+(1+a))((2a)-(1+a)) = (2a)^2-(1+a)^2$, which is still valid. The same happens in your case.